# Wordpress Custom Fields in own Single Page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields and a Custom Post Type.

Currently I am using a child theme from Block Theme 2022:
https://de.wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentytwo/

I am now trying to output the Custom Fields on the Single Page of the Custom Post Type as described here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-posts/

I have created my single-myCustomPostType.htm in the template folder, this is also used. However, I can not simply output my field here?

`<?php the_field('mycustomfield'); ?>`

If I then edit the template once in the Wordpress-Editor, HTML-Template changes no longer appear. Only when I discard the editor changes, the changes from the template appear.

Is there perhaps a better approach to output the custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

yes create shortcode and add in editor, to display you can use global $post to fetch data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know how to write a shortcode for the details page. I have now manually inserted the fields into the singlepage template via the Gutenberg editor as follows `[acf field="yourACFfieldName"]`

Answer (score 0):

> I have created my single-myCustomPostType.htm

.htm???

If it's not a typo it's the problem you're looking for.

Moreover single-myCustomPostType.PHP pages don't go in the Template folder, they go in the theme folder.

Comment: The new Block Based Themes for Full Site Editing have only HTML files in the templates, no PHP?

Comment: You're mixing different things... CPT templates must still be PHP files. Please read carefully again the tutorial you posted: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-posts/

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have added wp_reset function, after while or if condition i.e wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).